# Installing catkin on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building dependency tree
I can't seem to be able to install the 'catkin' package (I want catkin_make) on a recent Ubuntu Xenial installation:

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This seems to be caused by the presence of a more recent python-catkin-pkg in the packages.ros.org packages repositroy, that conflicts with the default package from Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache policy python-catkin-pkg 
python-catkin-pkg:
  Installed: 0.3.5-1
  Candidate: 0.3.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.5-1 500
        500 http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/packages/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/packages/ros/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        500 http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.2.10-2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267993/installing-catkin-on-ubuntu-16.04.3/) by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question : problem between chair and keyboard : was running on a machine without ROS environment setup, so my shell wasn't looking in /opt/ros/kinetic/bin
ros-kinetic-catkin package is installed and provices /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make, which is the one I want.

the Ubuntu 'catkin' package is just a lure…

---

Originally posted by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) with karma: 148 on 2017-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0